.net maui checkbox check mark color
I have the following check in my XAML
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="15" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SuperUser , Mode=TwoWay}" Color="White" BackgroundColor="Green" />
    <Label Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxText}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{x:Static strings:Strings.config_super_user}"/>
</StackLayout>

The result of this is almost what we want as seen below:

So by setting the background color of the checkbox we are able to affect the color of the Check mark.  The challenge I am facing is all the extra background color around the check box (The green that extends beyond the "color" area of the checkbox).  Any idea how to get rid of that?
UPDATE:
I tried the following of putting the checkbox inside a frame to cover up the extra background color that appears around the checkbox
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" Margin="0" >
            <Frame BorderColor="White" BackgroundColor="Orange" CornerRadius="0" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HasShadow="False" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="true" Color="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="0"  />
            </Frame>
            <Label Text="checkbox label" Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </StackLayout>

This ALMOST works.  What I end up with looks like the image below and you can see a slight bit of the background color still visible at the outer edge.

I have tried many things to get rid of that extra background color but nothing I try seems to be effective.  Any ideas on this??

Do you want to achieve like this output?

Do you need this to work on just Android or do you need it to render the same way on iOS (which isn't always easy) or other platforms?

WE need to support both -- I have started trying to put a frame around check box with a white background in order for the green outer frame to not be visible -- I can get it close but I always get a small row of pixels that are still visible.  I will post an update shortly to get ideas on this.

You may be on the right track by putting a frame under it, but what seemed to work better on my limited "farm" of 2 Android (A51 and S10) and 2 iOS devices (iPhone 11 and iPad) is to place a border over it instead. I have to tell you though, I'm concerned about iOS devices  since the native checkbox rendering is round. There's no guarantee this wouldn't be wonky on "some" devices but it works on what I've got.
If you try it, make sure to set InputTransparent on the Border otherwise the checkboxes won't toggle.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiCheckbox"
             x:Class="MauiCheckbox.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageBinding/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <StackLayout HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="15" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                <Grid 
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    WidthRequest="40" >
                    <CheckBox 
                        Margin="2"
                        IsChecked="{Binding SuperUser1}"
                        Color="White"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"/>
                    <Border 
                        Stroke="Yellow" 
                        StrokeThickness="14"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        InputTransparent="True"/>
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="Super User" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="15" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                <Grid 
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    WidthRequest="40" >
                    <CheckBox 
                        Margin="2"
                        IsChecked="{Binding SuperUser2}"
                        Color="White"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"/>
                    <Border 
                        Stroke="Yellow" 
                        StrokeThickness="14" 
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        InputTransparent="True"/>
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="Super User" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>


Androids


iOS


OK thank you @IV.  I will try that as soon as I get a minute.

OK -- This seems to work.. I don't like having to next a grid but when I tried with stacklayouts, I had the same challenge with a few pixels still being around the edge.  Thank you

No prob! And I understand about the extra grid. If this "scheme" proves reliable, you could just make yourself an extended custom CheckBoxEx: Grid class which would make it clean and easy to use in the xaml. Just a thought! Thx for the feedback!

You can completely build your own CheckBox appearance, by setting the original to Opacity=0 and then, draw your own underneath it. This would give you full background control, check mark shape, color, etc.
<Grid HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32">
    <Image Source="{Binding IsChecked, Source={Reference checkBox}, StringFormat='icon_check_{0}.png'}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Opacity="0" />
</Grid>

In the above, I define two SVG icons:
<!-- icon_check_false.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="22" height="22" fill="green" rx="3" ry="3" />
    <rect x="7" y="7" width="18" height="18" fill="white" rx="2" ry="2" />
</svg>

<!-- icon_check_true.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="22" height="22" fill="green" rx="3" ry="3" />
    <rect x="7" y="7" width="18" height="18" fill="white" rx="2" ry="2" />
    <path fill="green" d="M 9 17 l 5 5 l 9 -9 l -2 -2 l -7 7 l -3 -3 z" />
</svg>



Thank you for the information.  I was more looking for a way to make the current check box work without re-creating a brand new one.

